# Paint fractals simultaneously

Tags: java, swing, paint

I need to do a java code with Threads (implements Runnable()) for a college assigment. I need to draw 4 fractals at the same time ( with thread.sleep()). I already tried almost everything I knew, and this still doesn't working. So I cleaned up the source.

I have four classes ( four fractals). In my JPanel, i call a paint method to draw them ( they are recursive ). Can anyone save me please?

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
FractalTree tree = new FractalTree();
FractalCircle circle = new FractalCircle();
FractalSquare square = new FractalSquare();
FractalCircle2 circle2 = new FractalCircle2();

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setBackground(Color.black,g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    DrawBounds(g);

    tree.drawTree(g,200,290,-90,9);
    circle.drawCircle(g2,675,175,300);
    square.drawSquares(g, 200, 525, 100,7);
    circle2.drawCircle(g2,675,518,300);
}

public void DrawBounds(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(0,350,900,350);
    g.drawLine(450,0,450,700);
}

public void setBackground(Color c,Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 700);
}
```

}

```
public class FractalSquare{
public void drawSquares(Graphics g,int x, int y, int side ,int size){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    if(size >2){
        size--;
        g.fillRect(x-side/2, y-side/2, side, side);  
        side = side/2;
        x = x-side;
        y = y-side;
        drawSquares(g,x,y,side,size);
        drawSquares(g,x+side*2,y,side,size);
        drawSquares(g,x,y+side*2,side,size);
        drawSquares(g,x+side*2,y+side*2,side,size);
    } else return;
}
```

}

```
public class FractalCircle {
 public void drawCircle(Graphics2D g, float x, float y, float radius) {
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Float(x-radius/2, y-radius/2, radius,radius));
    if(radius > 2) {
        radius *= 0.75f;
        drawCircle(g,x, y, radius);
    } else return ;
}
```

}

```
public class FractalCircle2 {

 public void drawCircle(Graphics2D g, float x, float y, float radius) {
   Color color = new Color(255,0,255);
   g.setColor(color);
   g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Float(x-radius/2, y-radius/2, radius,radius));
    if(radius > 1) {
        radius *= 0.75f;
        drawCircle(g,x + radius/2, y, radius/2);
        drawCircle(g,x - radius/2, y, radius/2);
    } else return ;
}
```

}

```
public class FractalTree {

public void drawTree(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, double angle, int depth) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if (depth == 0) return;
    int x2 = x1 + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 5.0);
    int y2 = y1 + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 5.0);
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle - 20, depth - 1);
    drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle + 20, depth - 1);

}
```

}

Comment: Calling `setBackground(Color.black,g);` in you `paint` method is a bad idea. Painting should only ever paint the current state, never change it. In fact you should be using `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and should be calling `super.paintComponent` first

Comment: Another choice would be to paint to a `BufferedImage` and then paint this within your `paintComponent` method

Comment: I don't see any attempt to use `Thread`. Also, are these fractal classes a given? They look useless the way they are implemented holding just an instruction method.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Use `SwingWorker` to publish interim images, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25043676/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to render your fractals into separate images and copy them to the screen as the rendering progresses.

Swing will do most of the work for you if you wrap each fractal in a `JComponent`.

Here's an example using one of your fractals:

```
public class FractalPanel extends JPanel {
    final FractalSquare square = new FractalSquare(450, 350);

    public FractalPanel() {
        add(square);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FractalPanel fractalPanel = new FractalPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(fractalPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Thread squareThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                fractalPanel.square.render();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Interrupted");
            }
        });
        squareThread.start();
    }
}

class Fractal extends JComponent {
    final BufferedImage image;
    final Graphics2D offscreenGraphics;

    public Fractal(int width, int height) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        offscreenGraphics = image.createGraphics();
    }

    // Copy the offscreen image to the main graphics context
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        synchronized (image) { // synchronize with the render thread
            g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}

class FractalSquare extends Fractal {
    public FractalSquare(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    public void render() throws InterruptedException {
        drawSquares(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 100, 7);
    }

    public void drawSquares(int x, int y, int side, int size) throws InterruptedException {

        // Sleep for 10ms between frames
        Thread.sleep(10);

        if (size > 2) {
            size--;

            synchronized (image) { // synchronize with the draw thread
                offscreenGraphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                System.out.printf("Filling [%d, %d, %d, %d]\n", x - side / 2, y - side / 2, side, side);
                offscreenGraphics.fillRect(x - side / 2, y - side / 2, side, side);
            }

            // Tell Swing that we've updated the image and it needs to be redrawn
            repaint();

            side = side / 2;
            x = x - side;
            y = y - side;
            drawSquares(x, y, side, size);
            drawSquares(x + side * 2, y, side, size);
            drawSquares(x, y + side * 2, side, size);
            drawSquares(x + side * 2, y + side * 2, side, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `JFrame` which contains your `MainPanel`, add this code (a private `Thread` and its instance somewhere in the constructor):

```
private Thread threadRepaint;

...

threadRepaint = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                yourPanel.repaint();

                FractalSquare.decreaseLimit();
                FractalCircle.decreaseLimit();
                FractalCircle2.decreaseLimit();
                FractalTree.decreaseLimit();

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

threadRepaint.start();
```

The idea behind this, is that the Thread has to decrease the limit of your fractals each second (1000ms).

In each of your fractal classes you have to change the conditionals to something like this, and also add a static variable. That way, you'll see a progress with each iteration.

For your `FractalSquare`, it will stop when it gets to 2:

```
private static limit = 10;

...

public static void decreaseLimit() {
    if (limit > 2) limit--;
}

...
    // Inside your drawSquares method

    if (size > limit){
        ...
    } else return;
```

It's basically the same idea for each of your other fractals: you set an upper limit which will decrease over time (each iteration of the Thread). The decreasing limit will give the illusion of progression with each iteration.

Comment: What does this limit have to do with the question? The question asks how to draw 4 fractals concurrently and your question does not answer that.